# Has there been a recent change that is preventing tracked hands from showing in A-Frame VR accessed by Oculus Quest 2?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, oculus

Or is it just me. My own project using tracked hands was working fine yesterday, then today the hands stopped working. After reversing changes since then and still failing, I rechecked one example that was working correctly on Jan. 20: https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/hand-tracking/ - now, it is not showing hands, or allowing the controls to be used. The hands do show outside of VR when the controller is set down or inside VR when the Menu is invoked. On my device, Hand tracking is on, and the experimental 'WebXR experiences with hand and joint tracking', in chrome://flags, is enabled, both of which I believe are required and were enabled when this was working previously. Turned everything off and on several times, removed batteries, re-paired controllers and did a factory reset of the headset, all per instructions from Oculus support - to no avail. They said they will contact me after asking for invoice info. However it would be good to know if this is some other issue.  Can anyone confirm that the above example is, or is not, failing in Quest 2, or is there some other update or change that might be affecting this?

Comment: To clarify, the hands are there - just not visible - and can be used to summon the menu. Although they don't seem to work on the example controls, some of their data, such as leftHand.components['hand-tracking-controls'].indexTipPosition.x can be detected. Also, in the above example, even when the hands were previously showing on the initial entrance into VR and upon setting down the controllers, they would not show after toggling out of and back into VR until the page was reloaded.

Comment: Correction: leftHand.components['hand-tracking-controls'].indexTipPosition.x now fails, to 0. Also, testing the hand object after loading shows `hidden` set to false, `object3D.visible` set to true, and the correct default data, modelColor white and modelStyle mesh, Changing modelStyle to dots or changing the color has no effect. Assigning a position to the hand has no effect. Private mode, clearing cache no change. Firefox Reality browser has some other issues but does not show the hands in any case

Comment: Also, the examples at https://webxr-handtracking.vercel.app/ all now show black out completely after enter VR.

Comment: 2nd Oculus Quest 2 headset, same model, brand new, different supplier, failing in exactly the same way: hands not visible, not working in most cases, except to summon menu - individual headset defect not likely cause - something in aframe or oculus software has  changed

Answer (score 0):

Same for me on Quest 1.
The Three.js examples with Handtracking are working.
Try https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webxr#webxr_vr_handinput_cubes
I recognized that the oculus browser now says "...wants to enter with handtracking" So something changed in the oculus browser that has to be updated in the jslibraries.
But that will change again with chromium 88
I am on oculus browser 13.4.0.3.15 with chromium 87.0.4280

Comment: Yes, thanks you, you are correct, Three.js hand-tracking is working. I made an inquiry and was told that Oculus Browser has shipped a new version not compatible with A-Frame hand-tracking and A-Frame has yet to account for the changes. It is not known when that update will be ready.

Answer (score 0):

There must have been one cause I had the same problem.

Found [this](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/commit/97be8159d3769f4602e24ca870b754741f78777b) seemingly related fix in the A-Frame code, mostly bone name changes.

And [that](https://github.com/tete-github/a-frame-walkabout/commit/ac74cb8c60145ca4f7ac035d9df291e3940699c1)'s what helped me.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

I was calling for a previous version of the framework.